# Need to retrieve all main div in body

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a html code as follow

```
<body>
     <div class="dadas"><div class="col-md-12"><span>Hiiiii</span></div></div>
     <div class="ss"><div class="col-md-12"><span>User</span></div></div>
     <div class="sd"><div class="col-md-12"><span>This </span></div></div>
     <div class="ae"><div class="col-md-12"><span>Is an </span></div></div>
     <div class="asd"><div class="col-md-12"><span>Example</span></div></div>
</body>
```

I am trying to retrive the divs after body like this

```
1 = <div class="dadas"><div class="col-md-12"><span>Hiiiii</span></div></div>
2 = <div class="ss"><div class="col-md-12"><span>User</span></div></div>
3 = <div class="sd"><div class="col-md-12"><span>This </span></div></div>
4 = <div class="ae"><div class="col-md-12"><span>Is an </span></div></div>
5 = <div class="asd"><div class="col-md-12"><span>Example</span></div></div>
```

I'm trying each function:

```
$($("body div")).map(function(){ alert($(this).html())})
```

but I'm not getting proper output.

Comment: what u want? highlighting code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with your selector, you need to fetch only the direct `div` children of `body` element not all descendant `div` elements, so use `child-selector` instead of `descendant selector`.

Also to get the html markup of the `div` itself, you need to use `outerHTML` property.

```js
$($("body > div")).each(function() {
  snippet.log(this.outerHTML)
})
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dadas">
  <div class="col-md-12"><span>Hiiiii</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ss">
  <div class="col-md-12"><span>User</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sd">
  <div class="col-md-12"><span>This </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ae">
  <div class="col-md-12"><span>Is an </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="asd">
  <div class="col-md-12"><span>Example</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use just:

```
$("body > div")
```

which select only direct ancestors of `body`.

When you use just `$("body div")` it matches all `div` descendants of body no matter how nested they are.